# Scrape table loaded through javascript

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

I am trying to scrape a table which is being generated through javascript but I am struggling. My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'path\to\geckodriver')


# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://af.ktnlandscapes.com/'
driver.get(url)

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list-view"]')
table_html = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')

df = read_html(table_html)
print (df)

driver.close()
```

I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is the table has not fully loaded before you attempt to read the HTML from the table. To ensure the table is loaded, you can use the following code:

```
# get table -- first wait for table and all rows to fully load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='list-view']/tbody/tr")))

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='list-view']")
```

You can also just use plain Selenium to scrape the table -- there is no need to use `read_html` here, if that is not your preferred strategy. Here's some sample code scraping table values:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome();

driver.get("https://af.ktnlandscapes.com/")

# get table -- first wait for table to fully load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='list-view']/tbody/tr")))
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='list-view']")

# get rows
rows = table.find_elements_by_xpath("tbody/tr")

# iterate rows and get cells
for row in rows:

    # get cells
    cells = row.find_elements_by_xpath("td")

    # print cell contents
    for cell in cells:
        print(cell.text)

    # print newline to separate rows
    print('\n')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The above code sample fetches all table rows and cells, loops through them in a nested `for`, and prints the value of each cell. You can modify this to suit your program needs.

Output:

```
Networks
> Industry and research networks (networks)
A Network of Integrated Technolog...
Food and Drink, Plants...
 South West


Research Capabilities
> Livestock and Aquaculture Research Capabili...
Aberystwyth University (Institute...
Livestock and Aquaculture
 Wales


Research & Training Programmes
> Advanced Training Partnerships
Advanced Training Partnership for...
Livestock and Aquaculture
 Wales


Research Capabilities
> Livestock and Aquaculture Research Capabili...
Agri-Food and Biosciences Institu...
Livestock and Aquaculture
 Northern Ireland


Research Capabilities
> Plants and Crops Research Capabilities
Agri-Food and Biosciences Institu...
Plants and Crops
 Northern Ireland


Networks
> Industry Networks
Agri-Tech East
Livestock and Aquacult...
 East of England


Underpinning organisations
> Quality assurance bodies
Agricultural Industries Confedera...
Livestock and Aquacult...
 East of England


Underpinning organisations
> Trade associations
Agricultural Industries Confedera...
Livestock and Aquacult...
 East of England


Funders
> Levy bodies (funders)
Agriculture and Horticulture Deve...
Livestock and Aquacult...
 West Midlands


Underpinning organisations
> Levy bodies (underpinning)
Agriculture and Horticulture Deve...
Livestock and Aquacult...
 West Midlands


Innovation centres
> Centres for Agricultural Innovation
Agriculutral Engineering and Prec...
Livestock and Aquacult...
 Scotland


Research & Training Programmes
> Advanced Training Partnerships
AgriFood Advanced Training Partne...
AgriFood ATP, Plants a...
 East Midlands


Innovation centres
> Centres for Agricultural Innovation
Agrimetrics
Livestock and Aquacult...
 East of England


Networks
> Industry and research networks (networks)
Agrisearch
Livestock and Aquacult...
 Northern Ireland


Funders
> Research funding bodies (funders)
Agrisearch
Livestock and Aquacult...
 Northern Ireland


Networks
> Industry and research networks (networks)
Anaerobic Digestion Network
Livestock and Aquacult...
 South East


Key sector organisations
> UK Government organisations (key sector)
Animal and Plant Health Agency
Livestock and Aquacult...
 Nationwide


Research & Training Programmes
> Research and Technology Clubs
Animal Health Research Club
ARC, Livestock and Aqu...
 Nationwide


Underpinning organisations
> Professional organisations
Association of Applied Biologists
Livestock and Aquacult...
 West Midlands


Research Capabilities
> Livestock and Aquaculture Research Capabili...
Bangor University (College of Nat...
Livestock and Aquaculture
 Wales
```